# Clear form values after ajax submission.

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, reset

Live site- http://onetieva.com/#contact

This form is programmed with Ajax & PHP. After successful submission i want to hide user inputted info from input box.

Any idea how to do that.

[image]

Comment: In your ajax function, on success, simple hide the elements. It would help if you showed your ajax code.

Comment: You want to hide the input or clear it?

Comment: On success call of ajax clear all the values `$("#Id").val("")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `reset()` function to literally `reset` the form to it originally state.

If you are submitting the form with ajax... can be done with a callback function, but I suggest to do it with `.done()` along with `fail()` functions, to handle both scenarios.

So, will be something like:

```
$.post( "example_post_page.php", example_form_data )
    .done(function() {
        // Looks good
        // Let the user know with a message and then, clears the form.
        alert( "success" );
        $('#form-contact')[0].reset();
        // -------------------^ Same behavior as <input type="reset" /> element.
    })
    .fail(function() {
        // Show some warning message
        // Don't clear the data, so the user don't have to type all over again.
        alert( "error" );
    });
```

Of course, this is just an example, can be improved, like for example... replace those alerts, witha a nice modal box, add some warning class to the fields with errors, and so on...

More info: [jquery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: +1 for `reset`. You might use completely native DOM though, `document.getElementById("form-contact").reset()` :-) Or `$(…).each(function(){this.reset();})`

Answer (score 2):

You can add a class to all of your inputs, like '.input'. Then, in the success function you can use a class selector to clear all the inputs at once like this:

```
$('.input').val('')
```

That will save you writing a line of code for each input. Much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to clear the answers then Remove the validation, try this code

```
var $form = $('#form-contact');
$form.find('input, textarea').val('');
SimpleForm.clearErrors($form)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put a common class to all fields say e.g. - `clearMe`, and in your ajax's success section simply put `$(".clearMe").val("")`.